# How can I use the types of a conditionally imported module in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, dynamic-import

I have an optional and platform-dependent dependency in my project, that I want to import conditionally like this:

```js
import os from 'os';

export default async function doSomething(): Promise<foo | null> {
  if(os.type() === 'some os') {
    // "platform-dependent-module" exposes type "foo"
    const module = await import("platform-dependent-module");
    // do stuff
    return bar; // bar is of type foo
  }
  return null;
}
```

however this doesn't work, because the compiler `Cannot find name 'foo'`. Is it possible to expose the type definition without having to statically import the module?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it's possible to import and exposed type separately. So one can statically import the type like so:

```js
import type {foo} from 'module
```

and make use of the type, before dynamically loading the entire module. The final code would look something like this:

```js
import os from 'os';
import type {foo} from 'platform-dependent-module';

export default async function doSomething(): Promise<foo | null | Error> {
  if(os.type() === 'some os') {
    try {
      // "platform-dependent-module" exposes type "foo"
      const module = await import('platform-dependent-module');
      // do stuff
      return bar; // bar is of type foo
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [TypeScript's Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases).

And also make sure that the return type should be a promise in an async function.

And `catch` keyword should be replaced with `else` but there is no need of `else`.

```
import os from 'os';

type foo = any;

export default async function doSomething(): Promise<foo | null> {
  if(os.type() === 'some os') {
    // "platform-dependent-module" exposes type "foo"
    const module = await import("platform-dependent-module");
    // do stuff
    return bar; // bar is of type foo
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: But what's the point of this? Wouldn't it just make it `Promise<any | null>`? Isn't that kind of pointless?

Comment: @KerimGüney I don't know what is the purpose of the return type of `foo` here. In my point of view, I thought; maybe it is a custom data type. Or it is a class.  Not sure.. You can replace `Promise<any | null>` that's fine. But if there is only `foo`. The ts compiler don't know where this coming from. Even the js compilers. Because it is undefined. So you should define it or declare it as a type. When declared as a type, it considers as something global.

Comment: @KerimGüney If you don't know what is the type of that module,  refer this please https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown. You can set return type as unknown or any is fine too.

Comment: thank you for your input. `foo` is a custom type that is defined by the conditionally imported module. I was hoping there was some way to load the types of a module only, so I can use them as return types. This way it looks like any function that conditionally loads a module will just return some variant of `any` or `unknown` , which is a huge bummer.

Comment: @KerimGüney if the module exports its types, then you can. Otherwise, you have to define by yourself, simply.